# Not Getting any update notification from AppStore for macbook

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not getting any update notification regarding XCode. How to update my Xcode for Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

- Go to Apple Icon Menu -> System Preferences -> App Store
- Select Automatically check for updates
- This will give you notifications for available updates
- To check available updates for XCode or other Mac Apps simply click on Show Updates

You find this kind of screen:

[image]

**Edit:**

Open App store Application & go to Updates section. See below screen.

[image]

Hope it will you.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer. but In my macbook after following these steps it is not showing any update for XCode. In my macbook Xcode version is 6.2 and current version is 6.4

Comment: @SagarSnehi it will not give notification immediately, Open App Store Application & go to Updates section, check my Edited Answer

Comment: till now I am not getting any update notification about xCode update. pls help me.

Comment: @SagarSnehi can you post your Macbook configuration details on your question ?

Comment: OS X YoseMite version 10.10.,1 Mac Mini, processor : 2.3 ghz intel core i5, memory : 4 gb 1333 mhz ddr3, graphics: intel hd graphics 3000 384mb

Comment: Thats quite surprising you have latest OS version & still you not getting notification about XCode update. Do 1 thing Download latest Xcode from apple site. New Xcode version is openly available for all.